# I have a trouble with Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following problem in my Django project :

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template
>   /home/didier/Documents/Projects/inventory/inv/templates/index.html,
>   error at line 11 NoReverseMatch at /element Reverse for
>   'elements.views.element_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{u'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

*Views.py* is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Element
def hello(request):
    element = Element.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    title = 'Element list - RegiX'
    context = {
        'element': element,
        'title': title
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

ref element_detail(request, pk):
element = get_object_or_404(Element, pk=pk)
template = loader.get_template('element_detail.html')
context = {
    'element': element
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

*Urls.py*:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^element$', views.hello, name='hello'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.element_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

*index.html*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block page_title %}
    Element list | RegiX
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    {% for el in element %}
        <li>
            {{ el.manufacturer }} ::
            <a href="{% url 'elements.views.element_detail' pk=el.pk %}">
            {{ el.model }}
            </a>
            {{ el.date_purchase }} ::
            <img src="{{ el.image.url }}">
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html extend to index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <strong>RegiX Enterprise</strong>
    </header>
    <section>
        {% block login_content %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </section>
    <footer><small>RegiX :: powered By Didier Zúñiga</small></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Urls.py of settings:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('elements.urls', namespace='elements')),
    url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls', namespace='userprofiles')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL reverse in the template is wrong. By giving it the name `detail` within a namespace, you need use that name to reverse the URL, not the name of the view.

So this:

```
        <a href="{% url 'elements.views.element_detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```

Should be:

```
        <a href="{% url 'elements.detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists. Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: If you replaced `url 'elements.views.element_detail'`, thats impossible. There must be more code you aren't showing, or another template.

Comment: i added more than views.py, urls.py the settings and an extend of index.html, again thank

Comment: You had a namespace that was causing you trouble, try now.

Comment: Ready, it was the namespace. Thank u very much, you've me been very helpful